# How to connect user name password protected ms access 2000 database (.*mdb) using php

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc, ado

Hi guys i want to connect USERNAME,PASSWORD protected MS ACCESS 2000 (.*mdb) database using PHP, ODBC or any other database connection. But given below code show WARNING and doesn't connect to the database. please anyone help.

**CODE 1**

```
$mdbFilename = "C:\Documents and Settings\Hp\Desktop\Door\DB\IMSDB.mdb";
$user = 'test';
$password ='123';
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$mdbFilename;",$user,$password);

if($connection)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    exit("Connection Failed: ".$connection);
}
```

**WARNING MESSAGE**

```
Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] You do not have the necessary permissions to use the '(unknown)' object. Have your system administrator or the person who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you., SQL state 42000 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\punch\test.php on line 6
```

**Output -> Connection Failed**

**CODE 2**

I tried given below code also. there are no any ERRORS or WARNING MESSAGE but not connect to the access database.

```
$mdbFilename = "C:\Documents and Settings\Hp\Desktop\Door\DB\IMSDB.mdb";
$systemDbFilename = "C:\Documents and Settings\Hp\Desktop\Door\DB\SYSTEM.MDW";
$user = 'test';
$password ='123';

$adoCon = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$connection= $adoCon->Open("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$mdbFilename; SystemDB=$systemDbFilename;Uid=$user; Pwd=$password;");

if(($connection->State) > 0)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    exit("Connection Failed: ".$connection);
}
```

**Output -> Connection Failed**

---

## CORRECT ANSWER

Finally I found the answer. I tried PDO to connect ODBC.

**WORKING CODE**

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=D:\Door\DB\IMSDB.mdb;SystemDB=D:\Door\DB\SYSTEM.MDW;Uid=test;Pwd=123;");

    if($dbh)
    {
        echo "Connection Success";
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This is probably becuase the webserver process doesn't have read permission to `C:\Documents and Settings\Hp\Desktop\Door\DB\`

Comment: Hi guys Finally i find the answer. I tried PDO to connect ODBC.

//WORKING CODE

    try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=D:\Door\DB\IMSDB.mdb;SystemDB=D:\Door\DB\SYSTEM.MDW;Uid=test;Pwd=123;");
    
    if($dbh)
    {
    echo "Connection Success";
    }

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }